# Cypress custom command that returns functions

Tags: typescript, cypress

If I do the following:

```
export const test = () => ({
  yo: () => console.log('test'),
});
Cypress.Commands.add('test', test);

declare global {
  namespace Cypress {
    interface Chainable<Subject> {
       test: typeof test;
    }
  }
}
```

The above seems to cause no visible errors in the code.

However, when I do in my test `cy.test().yo()` I get `'yo' is not a function` error - but only when I run the test.

Answer (score 0):

cypress won't return the object directly. Instead it wraps it so that you chain the result. To access the content either use `then` or `invoke`

```js
it("runs command with then", () => {
  cy.test().then(r => r.yo())
})

it("runs command with invoke", () => {
  cy.test().invoke('yo')
})
```