# How to access Cypress.env-variables from a helper-file? Or how to access files and fixtures in a readable way

Tags: cypress

I'm working on a couple of projects, that ends up having a quite complex fixture structure. I usually end up with something like this:

```
cypress
  |- fixtures
     |- development
     |  |- tmp
     |  |  |- domain-hash.txt
     |  |
     |  |- secret
     |  |  |- admin-user.json
     |  |
     |  lang.json
     |
     |- staging
     |  |- tmp
     |  |  |- domain-hash.txt
     |  |
     |  |- secret
     |  |  |- admin-user.json
     |  |
     |  lang.json
     |
     |- production
     |  |- tmp
     |  |  |- domain-hash.txt
     |  |
     |  |- secret
     |  |  |- admin-user.json
     |  |
     |  lang.json
```

This is so I can run tests towards the different environments easily, where the fixtures usually varies.

I have then setup my `cypress.config.js` to have variables like this:

```
  env: {
    fixtureFolder: 'development',
    tmpFolder: '/tmp',
    secretFolder: '/secret',
    domainHashFileName: "domain-hash.txt",
  }
```

But this means that whenever I have to point to a file or path, that I end up with something like this:

```
// This path to this domainHash is not easy to read nor understand/debug.
let domainHash = Cypress.env( 'fixtureFolder' ) + '/' + Cypress.env( 'tmpFolder' ) + Cypress.env( 'domainHashFileName' );

// I use that path like this:
cy.task( 'readFileMaybe', domainHash )
  .then( ( domainHash ) => {
    ...
    ...
  });
```

### The overarching question

I want to be able to reference which file/fixture it needs to load/delete as shortly and easily readable as possible, so the code doesn't get bloated as shown above, every time I have to access a fixture or a file.

---

### Solution attempt 1: Define a bunch of different paths in `cypress.config.js`

I tried having these lines in `cypress.config.js`:

```
domainHashFileName: "domain-hash.txt",
domainHashFromFixture: "development/tmp/domain-hash.txt",
domainHashFromRoot: "cypress/fixtures/development/tmp/domain-hash.txt",
```

But that means that I would have to define three variables for each one. Not ideal.

---

### Solution attempt 2: Add it as a Cypress-command

Because of the async nature of these Cypress-functions, then I would have to [chain the hell out of this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74293250/1766219), which just moves my problem somewhere else.

Comment: AFAIk `Cypress.env()` should be accessible there. I'm not entirely sure why you're getting NotANumber (NaN), but for Solution Attempt 1 have you tried using string interpolation with back ticks? Something like \``cypress/fixtures/${Cypress.env('fixtureFolder')}/${folderName}\``

Comment: Thanks @agoff . I must have had a typo or something. I got it working now, so I moved that solution attempt into an answer.

Answer (score 4):

To me, any particular run is fixed with either 'production', 'development', or 'staging'. Maybe it uses the default `fixtureFolder` you have in `cypress.config.js` or an override by command line.

Whichever it is, it's fixed for the whole run - you can add a line to `setupNodeEvents` and just use `cy.fixture()` normally.

**cypress.config.js**

```js
const { defineConfig } = require("cypress");
const fs = require('fs')

module.exports = defineConfig({
  e2e: {
    setupNodeEvents(on, config) {
      config.fixturesFolder = `cypress/fixtures/${config.env.fixtureFolder}`
      return config
    },
    env: {
      fixtureFolder: 'staging'   // can be over-ridden on the command line
    },
  },
})
```

**test**

```js
cy.fixture('/temp/domain-hash.txt')  // from defined section of fixtures
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to make a helper-function: `cypress/support/utils/helpers.js`

with the contents:

```js
export const getFullEnvFolderPath = (folderName) => {
  return 'cypress/fixtures/' + Cypress.env('fixtureFolder') + '/' + folderName;
}

export const getEnvFolderPath = (folderName) => {
  return Cypress.env('fixtureFolder') + '/' + folderName;
}

// ... with several other functions.
```

In my e2e-tests, I can do this:

```
import { getFullEnvFolderPath } from "../../support/utils/helpers";

...
...

let domainHash = getFullEnvFolderPath( Cypress.env( 'domainHashFileName' ) );
cy.task( 'readFileMaybe', domainHash )
  .then( ( domainHash ) => {
    ...
    ...
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the main difference between fixtures is the root folder name based on the environment the tests are running in. I'm not sure why you have env vars called `tmpFolder` and `secretFolder` mapped to values of `/tmp` and `secret` that don't look like they'll ever change.

So based on that I have two suggestions:

1. Set one `env` var for the environment (production, staging, development) the tests are running on and just interpolate the string into the directory path
2. Use `cy.fixture()` to read fixture files

```js
// cypress.config.js
fixturesFolder: 'cypress/fixtures',
env: {
  system: 'production' // set this depending on environment
}

// Test code
const env = Cypress.env('system')
cy.fixture(`${env}/temp/domain-hash.txt`).then(domainHash => /* code */ );
cy.fixture(`${env}/secret/admin-user.json`).then(adminUser => /* code */ );
cy.fixture(`${env}/lang.json`).then(lang => /* code */ );
```

https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/fixture